# Ubuntu 18.04 Install Problems

Tags: boot, server, 18.04, system-installation, macbook-pro

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on a Macbook Pro. I downloaded the file and used Etcher to flash it to a USB from within Windows 10. I booted it up on the Mac. When I selected the drive and clicked to continue, I got the message; "error: file /boot/ not found." Then it goes to a blank screen. I then tried to write the file to a DVD and try booting from it but I got the same response. I had Ubuntu on this Mac in the past so I do not know what is going on. Will someone please help?

Comment: There's a chance the ISO you downloaded is corrupt.

Comment: I have downloaded it a few times and I always get the same issues.